# Oauth login and registration with custom username, express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, registration

I use **node.js+express.js** stack, users can reigster/login with twitter and facebook, and also can register with my native registration form. I use everyauth to handle with Twee and Fb.

**The question is:**
Is there a simple solution to register users with third-party oauth services while allowing them to change it's username?

example:
User logins to site with twitter first time -> he gets form where he adds his **CUSTOM USERNAME and email**.

While he logins next time I need to check in db his **CUSTOM USERNAME** and not his twitter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. On first login attempt you authenticate the user via twitter using the `node-oauth` module. Here's a [tutorial](http://codetheory.in/how-to-use-twitter-oauth-with-node-oauth-in-your-node-js-express-application/). After the authentication process is done, twitter sends a unique ID in its results, you store that with oauth token and secret (if you want to) inside your DB. Also save these data in Session and show a form where you ask for the user to choose a username of his wish. Use that and store in DB.

Next time, when he tries to authenticate again, you just check against the unique ID stored in  your database (not the username really).

Comment: so I need to store user's twitter accessToken in db as well?

Comment: yes you can, and then update that everytime the user tries to authenticate :)

Comment: but if service changed the token -> while finding with stored token in db the user will be interpreted like new one

Comment: Nope, remember you need to check against the ID that comes in the twitter's oauth data. you'll notice in the result object there's a property called 'id' - it's a unique ID assigned by twitter for every user that won't change. Just `console.log` the incoming twitter data and you'll get the idea.

Comment: Btw, do you now, @Rishabh, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999874/setup-page-on-first-login-express-js ?