# Setup page on first login, express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using **Passport.js** to authorize user into my express.js app.

I want to show setup page when user logins first time.

Can I do this with Passport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Code MUST be modified mor your db, etc.
Init The User:

```
var user = new User({ ... });
user.newUser = true;
```

And

```
app.get("/account",requireLogin, function(req,res){
    if(req.user.newUser){
        req.user.newUser = false;
        req.user.save(function(err){
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            res.redirect("/setup");
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place *newuser* attribute within the database as answered by "Ari Porad" but the better approach would be to change it to *false* when you are done with account first time setup because we dont really know if the user has completed his first time setup or not (browser may crash and he might not be able to complete it :D ) , so its better not to modify the "newuser" attribute as *false* on first visit but rather you should be modifying it after he has submitted the data that we require on the first visit.